# Extend Window Beyond Bottom of Screen on MacOS

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, external-display, screen-capture, macos-highsierra

I would like to extend one of my application windows below the bottom of the screen. I can easily extend it beyond the left/right sides (simply drag it to one side, then resize, and repeat), however I haven't been able to achieve a vertical resize of the window.

Is there a modification to the OS I can do to enable this behavior? I've also looked at simulating an external display, as I believe a higher resolution external display does enable resizing below the bottom of the screen; however I haven't seen anyway to make this work, and I don't have access to a real external display currently.

If you're wondering why I need to do this, it's for a screen capture software—I need to fit a large amount of content into the window at once.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to unlock expending a window vertically beyond the screen.

1/ You may try to run an apple script like this:

```
tell application "XXX"
  set bounds of front window to {x, y, width, height}
end tell
```

with setting a high value for `height`. Like `{30, 30, 1200, 4000}`

2/ If it's to capture a web page, there are [plugins for that](https://www.softwarehow.com/take-full-webpage-screenshot/).

3/ Or [Snagit allows capturing with scrolling feature](https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007803871-Scroll-to-Capture). But it won't be free after the trial expires.

Comment: Thanks for the response @yoric. Due to the nature of the application (Google Earth), #1 is the only option that would work for me. I tried it, however I'm getting this: `error "Google Earth Pro got an error: Can’t set window 1 to {30, 30, 1200, 4000}." number -10006 from window 1`.

I also tried [this approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39900/move-position-of-an-application-window-from-the-command-line-on-osx), however I'm getting: `error "Google Earth Pro got an error: Can’t make position of window 1 into type specifier." number -1700 from position of window 1 to specifier`.

Comment: @LeopoldJoy I get the same error with you. It seems like `Google Earth Pro` cannot be controlled by Apple Script